# Why QFileDialog::getOpenFileName doesn't work?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qfile, qfiledialog

In the String the path is right, but it doesn't put strings in my table . No Error or Warnings. When I do this for example:

```
 meinModel->setData(filename, filename);
```

it views the Strings : E:/test.txt

I have a QTableView and a QAbstractTableModel.

```
 void View::OpenFileButtonClicked()
    {
        QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, QString(), QString()
                                             ,tr("Data (*.txt)"));
        fileMy = new QFile(filename);
        QTextStream stream (&*fileMy);  
        while (!stream.atEnd())
            {
              QString line = stream.readLine();
              QStringList list = line.split(",");
              QString firststring;
              firststring = (list.first());
              QString secondstring;
              secondstring = (list.last());
             // Strings are sent to Model which view they in my tableview.
              meinModel->setData(firststring, secondstring);
            }        
    }
```

Strange, because this works:

```
  void View::FileButtonClicked()
{
    QString fileName;
    if (txtPfad->text().length() > 0 )
    {
        fileMy = new QFile(txtPfad->text());
    } 
    else 
    {   fileMy = new QFile("E:\\test.txt"); }

    if (!fileMy->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("ERROR"), tr("Daten konnten icht eingelesen werden"));
        return;
    }
    QTextStream stream (&*fileMy);  
    while (!stream.atEnd())
        {
         QString line = stream.readLine();
         QStringList list = line.split(",");
         QString firststring;
         firststring = (list.first());
         QString secondstring;
         secondstring = (list.last());
         meinModel->setData(firststring, secondstring);
        }   
}
```

Comment: `&*fileMy` is actually the value of `fileMy`, if you cancel the `QFileDialog` the returned string will be empty

Comment: Create QFile object on the stack. You don't need to keep this pointer outside of this method. Otherwise you'll need to delete every object created with `new`.

Comment: my setData works perfectly. i only must send her 2 Strings. in other Methods where i use  meinModel->setData(firststring, secondstring); it works.. only in this Methode..

Answer (score 1):

You missed opening of a file in `OpenFileButtonClicked`:

```
if (!fileMy->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("ERROR"), tr("Daten konnten icht eingelesen werden"));
    return;
}
```